# Hide the related Many2One field when creating a record from a one2Many Relationship

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

i have a One2many relationship.

```
class Osg(models.Model):
        _name = "men_projet.osg"
        _rec_name = 'nom'
        sequence = fields.Char('Sequence', readonly=True)
        nom = fields.Char('Nom')
        responsable = fields.Many2one('res.partner')
        programme_id = fields.Many2one('men_projet.programme')
        os = fields.One2many('men_projet.os', 'osg_id')  <---- My One2many field.


class Os(models.Model):
    _name = "men_projet.os"
    _rec_name = "nom"

    sequence = fields.Char('Sequence', readonly=True)
    nom = fields.Char('Nom')
    responsable = fields.Many2one('res.partner')
    osg_id = fields.Many2one('men_projet.osg') <---- The inverse field
```

My Goal : When adding a new record to the One2Many table (Using the 'add a line button') the modal/pop-up window has the inverse Many2one field (Dropdown) which makes no sense since i'm already coming from the Model and having it's value.

So i want to hide it when creating the Model 'Os' from the One2Many field while letting it visible when creating it from it's own action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a FormView for that One2many field.
Example:-

```
<field name="os" >
   <form>
       <group>
           <field name="sequence"/>
           <field name="nom"/>
           <field name="responsable"/>
       </group>
   </form>                    
</field>
```